# Remove &#58 character from string

Tags: php

I crawl a web to get a title

```
$title = strip_tags($link1->plaintext);
```

but in the result, there is a result like `Data Mining&#58  Concepts and Techniques`

How to remove that `&#58` ? thank you

Comment: Looks like a broken HTML Entity (missing the final semicolon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `&#58;` is a [character entity reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_entity_reference) for a colon, but your example is incorrectly terminated (missing ending semicolon). You can fix unterminated references with the following (rather naive) regular expression:

```
$broken = "Data Mining&#58 Concepts and Techniques";
$fixed = preg_replace('/(&#x?[a-e0-9]+)\b/i', '$1;', $broken);
```

You can then use `html_entity_decode`:

```
echo html_entity_decode($fixed); // Data Mining: Concepts and Techniques
```

Answer (score 0):

`$title = str_replace("&#58", "", strip_tags($link1->plaintext));`

Comment: You may want to explain your answer in a little more detail; rather than just post code *explain* what it does.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's pretty obvious, no?

Comment: You'd be surprised. Also, why not attempt to repair such broken entities? A regular expression like `&#\d\b' would find these and allow you to add the missing `;`, then decode the entities.